# Why does a query string return a 404 error?

Tags: uri, 9

I recently upgraded from Drupal 8 to Drupal 9 and noticed a problem that occurs when the URL has a query string. For example for the following URL Drupal throws a 404 page not found.

`https://example.com/2021/07/how-drive-cruise-ship&ct=ga&cd=EAEYACoTMzczMDU5MTUxNjcwNDQyMzUxNzIcN2RiZjYwOGY4MzE2NmM3OTpjby51azplbjpHQg&usg=AFQjCNEa2-Hx3zqnQ59AJFnde_ORtLTvgA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string is badly formatted.  It needs a `?`:

`https://example.com/2021/07/how-drive-cruise-ship?&ct=ga&cd=EAEYACoTMzczMDU5MTUxNjcwNDQyMzUxNzIcN2RiZjYwOGY4MzE2NmM3OTpjby51azplbjpHQg&usg=AFQjCNEa2-Hx3zqnQ59AJFnde_ORtLTvgA`